# Problem when inserting two consecutive lines to the database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have this function and it is working perfectly

```
       public  DemandeConge Creat(DemandeConge DemandeConge)
    {

        try
        {
            var _db = Context;
            int numero = 0;
            //??CompanyStatique
            var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
            int currentCompanyId = int.Parse(session[2].Value);

            numero = _db.DemandeConge.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(t => t.companyID == currentCompanyId)
                          .Select(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.NumeroDemande))
                          .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                          .Max();
            numero++;
            DemandeConge.NumeroDemande = numero.ToString();
            //_db.Entry(DemandeConge).State = EntityState.Added;
            _db.DemandeConge.Add(DemandeConge);
            _db.SaveChanges();

            return DemandeConge;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But just when i try to insert another leave demand directly after inserting one (without waiting or refreshing the page )
An error appears saying that this new demand.id exists

I think that i need to add refresh after saving changes?
Any help and thanks

Comment: How do you know it's working at all? That `catch` statement is hiding the errors and `_db.DemandeConge.AsEnumerable()` is loading the entire table in memory. ` Convert.ToInt32(p.NumeroDemande)` means there's a bug in the table and instead of storing the number as a number, it's stored as a string

Comment: Well i know it has some things to optimise but it working because i tested it

Comment: And finally, it looks like this is an attempt to generate a key with the `MAX+1` technique, something that's guaranteed to generate duplicate keys. What if *two* requests try to generate an ID at roughly the same time? They'll get the same MAX. What if the latest entries are deleted? Their IDs will be regenerated and reused

Comment: The point is, it's not working. It's not just optimization, it has fundamental bugs that shouldn't be there. Just use an `IDENTITY` constraint in the database and let the ORM do its job. The code is *hiding* all errors, so there's no way to say what's wrong

Comment: Another problem is that this code can *easily* perform 10 DELETEs and 50 UPDATEs. Changes are cached in the DbContext and stored in a single transaction when `SaveChanges` is called. *Remove* both the `catch` clause and the call to `SaveChanges`. When the entire operation (request?) completes, call `SaveChanges` just once to have everything sent to the database

Comment: You'll have to remove that `catch` anyway, to find out what's wrong. At the very least, log the exception

Answer (score 2):

Code like this:

```
        numero = _db.DemandeConge.AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(t => t.companyID == currentCompanyId)
                      .Select(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.NumeroDemande))
                      .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
                      .Max();
        numero++;
```

Is a very poor pattern. You should leave the generation of your "numero" (ID) up to the database via an Identity column. Set this up in your DB (if DB First) and set up your mapping for this column as DatabaseGenerated.Identity.

However, your code raises lots of questions.. Why is it a String instead of an Int? This will be a bugbear for using an identity column.

The reason you will want to avoid code like this is because each request will want to query the database to get the "max" ID, as soon as you get two requests running relatively simultaneously you will get 2 requests that say the max ID is "100" before either can reserve and insert 101, so both try to insert 101. By using Identity columns the database will get 2x inserts and give them an ID first-come-first-serve. EF can manage associating FKs around these new IDs automatically for you when you set up navigation properties for the relations. (Rather than trying to set FKs manually which is the typical culprit for developers trying to fetch a new ID app-side)

If you're stuck using an existing schema where the PK is a combination of company ID and this Numero column as a string then about all you can do is implement a retry strategy to account for duplicates:

```
const int MAXRETRIES = 5;

var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
int currentCompanyId = int.Parse(session[2].Value);
int insertAttemptCount = 0;

while(insertAttempt < MAXRETRIES)
{
    try
    {
        numero = Context.DemandeConge
            .Where(t => t.companyID == currentCompanyId)
            .Select(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.NumeroDemande))
            .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
            .Max() + 1;
        DemandeConge.NumeroDemande = numero.ToString();
        Context.DemandeConge.Add(DemandeConge);
        Context.SaveChanges();
        break;
    }
    catch (UpdateException)
    {
        insertAttemptCount++;
        if (insertAttemptCount >= MAXRETRIES)
            throw; // Could not insert, throw and handle exception rather than return #null.
    }
}
return DemandeConge;
```

Even this won't be fool proof and can result in failures under load, plus it is a lot of code to work around a poor DB design so my first recommendation would be to fix the schema because coding like this is prone to errors and brittle.